# Obtaining the index of the largest element of an array without also obtaining the value

Tags: arrays, matlab

I understand that [M,I] = max(A) will get for me the value of the largest element in the array and also its index.

Is there a convenient way to obtain the index without also (unnecessarily, from my perspective) also obtaining the value?

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this so that I can just write index = function(A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always put a `~` for any return you don't want, so, in your case, you'd have `[~,index] = max(A)`.

Comment: It might be prudent to add that you don't have a choice but to call the two-output version of `max` if you want the index of where it occurs.  Just my two cents.  This does answer the question though.